# camel-mail : can't send a mail with attachments

Tags: email, apache-camel, attachment, mime

EDIT : If anybody comes here with a similar problem looking for an answer, sorry I don't have any helpful advice, I just gave up and wrote everything in "pure" Java with the org.apache.commons.mail library. The Apache Camel route is just detecting the presence of file and giving the file address to my Java bean.

Also solved the issue underlined by Ninja Code Monkey about using the consumerTemplate to grab other files.

Original post below :

---

I'm working on a Camel Route that is supposed to send emails according to some file input (a home-made XML file listing recipient addresses, subject, body, etc.).

It's working fine for emails without attachment, but I'm now trying to add support for attachments and I keep getting the following exception :
`javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;`

I've checked Camel's page about [mail](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html), and the code samples in the unit-tests but I fail to see where I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my route in Java DSL :

```
from("file: ...options... ")
    .setHeader("To",xpath("/root/destinataire/text()"))
    .setHeader("Subject",xpath("/root/sujet/text()"))
    .setHeader("BodyPath",xpath("/root/body/text()"))
    .setHeader("AttachementPath",xpath("/root/attachement/text()"))

    .process(new org.apache.camel.Processor() {
        public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            consumerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
            String body_content = consumerTemplate.receiveBody("file: ...options... ", String.class);
            //I'm using the consumerTemplate to get the file containing the body, works fine
            exchange.getIn().setBody(body_content);
        }
    })

    .process(new org.apache.camel.Processor() {
        public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String attachementPath = exchange.getIn().getHeader("AttachementPath", String.class);
            //Camel's webpage and unit-tests are using addAttachment with DataHandler(FileDataSource), so I'm doing the same
            DataHandler fileAttachment = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(attachementPath));
            exchange.getIn().addAttachment("filename.xxx", fileAttachment);
        }
    })

    //the exception is thrown at the next instruction :
    .to("smtp://esb@localhost: ... ?password= ...")
;
```

While googling around the issue, I found some related informations, but they are dealing with different Java objects such as `MimeBodyPart`, and the method addAttachment is requiring a `DataHandler`, so I don't really know how I'm supposed to deal with this.

As for configuration info, we're running Camel 2.10.4 on Java 6 (yes it's outdated, we're working on an upgrade, but this email route is supposed to be in production way before the Camel upgrade).

EDIT : additional info, when I'm checking the DataHandler object with `fileAttachment.getContentType()`, it is giving me "text/plain" for text files, or "image/jpeg" and "image/png" with images.

From my understanding, it means that my problem is not with the MIME type of the attachment, but rather with the way the body and attachment are blended together.

Comment: The first Processor should NOT be using (much less creating) a ConsumerTemplate to receive a file body.  The body of the message should already be populated via the producing endpoint: from("file...")

As for the attachment, try reading in the file to text, then creating a DataHandler like so:
new DataHandler(text, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

Comment: The original endpoint `from("file:...")` is receiving an XML file that I'm parsing to get the following information : recipients, subject of the mail, where to find the file containing the body, and where to find attachments if there's any. After that I no longer need the body to contain that XML file, so I'm replacing it with the actual body of the mail.

Do you think it's a wrong way to do it ? If I start by consuming the mail's body, how can I get the other information ?

I'm going to try what you said for the text, and I'll edit later to say how it went.

Comment: Seems I can't edit after a while, and there was only 32 char left anyway. So I tried like you said, and even with `new DataHandler("this is a string","text/plain");` it's still giving me that exception. I think the issue is not with the MIME type of the attachment (already checked with `fileAttachment.getContentType()` , I'm getting values that seem normal), but rather with the MIME type of the mail's body, or the way the body and attachment get linked together. Or maybe the MIME type of resulting mix?